# Programmatically setting HtmlDesignAssociated value

Tags: 2013, feature-receiver, elements-xml, composed-looks

I'm deploying a composed look from the server (including the .spcolor, .spfont, master.html and master.preview files), but I cannot get the field Associated File to select. I've tried setting it in just the `elements.xml` file as well as the event receiver's `FeatureActivated` event.

Elements.xml:

```
<File Path="Master\corporate.html" Url="corporate.html" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="True">
  <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Html Master Page"></Property>
  <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="15"></Property>
  <Property Name="HtmlDesignAssociated" Value="TRUE"></Property>
  <Property Name="FSObjType" Value="0"></Property>
</File>
```

And the code-behind:

```
SPList masterGallery = web.Lists.TryGetList("Master Page Gallery");
SPListItemCollection masterItems = masterGallery.Items;

for (int m = 0; m < masterItems.Count; m++)
{
    SPListItem page = masterItems[m];
    if(page["Name"].ToString() == "corporate.html")
    {
        page["HtmlDesignAssociated"] = true;
        page.Update(); // forgot to include this line
    }
}
```

Note: I've left out other irrelevant code.

Comment: Just to verify, are you calling page.Update() in your event receiver code?

Comment: Yes, page.Update() is being called. I forgot to include that line. Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently trying to set the field `HtmlDesignAssociated` from the `elements.xml` file in a Module won't work.

Once I took that out, the code in the event receiver worked and my `master.html` file now has an associated `master.master`.

I modified the code a little to utilize `SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl` instead of `web.GetList` or `web.Lists.TryGetList("whatever")`. Here's the code that works:

```
var masterGallery = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(relativePath, "_catalogs/masterpage");
SPList master = web.GetList(masterGallery);
SPListItemCollection masterItems = master.Items;

for (int m = 0; m < masterItems.Count; m++)
{
    SPListItem page = masterItems[m];
    if (page["Name"].ToString() == "corporate.html")
    {
        page["HtmlDesignAssociated"] = true;
        page.Update();
    }
}
```